# Массивы c++ arduino

Tags: c++, массивы, arduino

Создаю массив `int names[] = {1,1}`; 
Вывожу, и получаю:

```
1
1
257
1
1
26996
11625
12592
80
-32157
25427
309
29249
30052
28265
11631
12336
```

Что это еще за 15 ячеек создалось ? Спасибо :)

Comment: А каким образом выводите?

Comment: видимо за пределы массива вышли, а там мусор

Comment: @post_zeew for (int i =0; names[i] != NULL; i++) {
    Serial.println(names[i]); 
  } А как нужно ? Если я не знаю конца

Comment: Вы же можете посчитать количество элементов массива. Например, используя `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что вы выводите массив, пока не встретится какое-то граничное значение. И эти дополнительные 15 элементов - это то, что хранится в памяти за пределами массива, пока не встретится это граничное значение.

В этом случае ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение, так как происходит обращение к памяти за пределами массива.

EDIT: Данное предложение

```
for (int i =0; names[i] != NULL; i++) { Serial.println(names[i]); }
```

некорректное, так как ваш массив содержит только 2 элемента, и ни один элемент не равен 0. Поэтому происходит выход за пределы массива.`

Вместо  этого цикла вы могли бы записать

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names ); i++) { Serial.println(names[i]); }
```

Илм бы вы могли объявить массив, имеющий граничное значение 0. Например

```
int names[3] = {1,1};
         ^^^ 
for (int i =0; names[i] != 0; i++) { Serial.println(names[i]); }
```